# How to put the Kindle Fire in airplane mode?

Tags: wi-fi, amazon-kindle-fire, airplane-mode

I use the Amazon *Kindle Fire* (Android 2.3.4) model no: `D01400 FCCID:ZEV-1229`. I use this device in developing Android apps.

In my device WiFi is available, and also cyberoam for security purposes. I want to test the device is connected or not connected with WiFi.

I know if you want to check the network connection and you have cyberoam then you want put your device in airplane mode. How can I do that?

Comment: @Izzy have u any idea about this?

Comment: Nope. If I had, I would have written. Just updated your post to make it better readable and easier to find for those being familiar with the Fire. I have no idea how far Amazon might have modified Android. You might have an entry in the power-menu (long press power button while screen is on) or not. There should be an option in *Settings->Networks & Wireless* -- but as "no network" would mean "no current ads on the lockscreen", Amazon might have removed that as well. I'm not familiar with their devices, sorry.

Comment: @Izzy i try all of possiblity.

Comment: Please report back then, luck or not. "Not being familiar with" does not mean "not being willing to learn" :)

Answer (score 1):

On the original Kindle Fire Airplane mode does not seem to exist, but you can turn off wireless using these directions:

1. Tap the Quick Settings (the Gear) icon in the top right hand corner of the Home screen.
2. Tap **Wi-Fi**.
3. Ensure Wireless Networking switch is in the **off** position.

On the new Kindle Fire you can enable airplane mode by doing the following:

1. Swipe down from the top of the screen and tap **Wireless**.
2. Tap **On** next to Airplane Mode

Comment: i try first one .but it's not working in where Cyberoam is available.

Comment: Can you use Dalvik Debug Monitor (per the instructions [here](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-any-kindle-fire/)) to take a screen shot of what you do see so that I can get a better idea of the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: i use the simple instruction to put  device in airplan mode.but i can`t put if cyberoam is available here. i follow the simple step but i can't success.and another thing my device is first one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a metric boatload of [Airplane Mode apps on the Play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=airplane%20mode&c=apps). You might find one there that meets your needs.